# How does rostest work with catkin?

Tags: ros, catkin, rostest, master, gtest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [camera_info_manager](http://ros.org/wiki/camera_info_manager) package uses **rostest** to launch a ROS graph for unit testing.

Launching it explicitly works:

```
$ rostest camera_info_manager unit_test.test
```

But, if I run the test in a catkin build, it fails to start the rostest master. It hangs, waiting for me to start **roscore** by hand. After that, it completes the test successfully.

```
$ make run_tests
[ 42%] Built target camera_calibration_parsers
[ 57%] Built target camera_info_manager
[ 71%] Built target gtest
[ 85%] Built target gtest_main
[100%] Built target unit_test
[100%] Built target clean_test_results
[100%] Built target tests
-- run_tests.py: execute commands
  /home/joq/ros/hydro/devel/lib/camera_info_manager/unit_test --gtest_output=xml:/home/joq/ros/hydro/build/test_results/camera_info_manager/gtest-unit_test.xml
[ERROR] [1359843932.846640561]: [registerPublisher] Failed to contact master at [vision-4.local:11311].  Retrying...
```

How is this supposed to work, now?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54075/how-does-rostest-work-with-catkin?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2013-02-02

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The camera_info_manager package mixes gtest and rostest wrongly. Currently it specifies two tests: a  plain gtest (`catkin_add_gtest`) and a rostest (`add_rostest`).

The rostest invocation should work - try to call `make run_tests_camera_info_manager_rostest_...`. What fails is the gtest you have declared  in CMakeLists.txt. It expects it to be a plain gtest file which does not require any ROS environment.

Since `unit_test` is not a plain gtest you should just build it as a normal executable without registering as a gtest through the `catkin_add_gtest` macro.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-04**:
Thanks, Dirk, that works. For future reference, where is this documented? This page only talks about rosbuild with gtest and rostest: http://ros.org/wiki/gtest#Building_and_running_tests

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-04-17**:
@joq I cannot seem to find document for testing with `catkin` in general. I just started adding catkin section [here](http://ros.org/wiki/gtest) while I'm learning `gtest` in `C++` at the same time. Edition/Addition is appreciated.

**Comment by [hersh](https://answers.ros.org/users/97/hersh/) on 2013-07-29**:
I added a github issue here: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/258 requesting a new cmake macro for this situation.